# Elessar - fix touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, elessar

Just been trying to get multiple ranges working using [elessar](https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar)

Its a great library although not well documented. I got everything going but it doesn't seem to work on touch devices. No error thrown in the console either.

Can someone help me fix it.

Here is an example:

```
var r = new RangeBar({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
    /*readonly: true,*/
  values: [
    [0, 4],
    [10, 14]
  ],
    valueFormat: function(a) {return a.toFixed(1)},
  valueParse: function(a) {return parseInt(a)},
  snap: 0.1,
  minSize: 0.5,
  barClass: 'bar',
  rangeClass: 'bar-range',
  allowDelete: true
});
$('[role=main]').prepend(r.$el).on('changing', function(ev, ranges) {
  $('pre.changing').html('changing ' + JSON.stringify(ranges, null, 2));
}).on('change', function(ev, ranges) {
  $('pre.changing').after($('<pre>').html('changed ' + JSON.stringify(ranges, null, 2)));
});
```

http://codepen.io/praneybehl/pen/MYXVEx

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar/commit/51a9b6e9f5801c31ed7cd3b1e37a46984a5b6ecb) in Elessar. It's fixed in version 1.8.4.